# Azure linux uptime -s increasing

Tags: linux, azure, uptime

Do you know why uptime -s increasing in Azure platform?

```
hostname@ubuntu:~$ date
Thu Jan  4 15:00:04 CET 2018
hostname@ubuntu:~$ uptime -s
2018-01-01 00:52:15
```

After 10 minutes:

```
hostname@ubuntu:~$ date
Thu Jan  4 15:10:18 CET 2018
hostname@ubuntu:~$ uptime -s
2018-01-01 00:52:24
```

hostname@ubuntu:~$ ps -Afl
F S UID         PID   PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
4 S root          1      0  0  80   0 - 30225 -      **Jan01 ?        00:00:49** /sbin/init

This host works stable

Answer (score 0):

The apparent time that your system was booted, as shown by `uptime -s`, changed because the system clock changed.

Let us look at the [source code for `uptime`](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/uptime.c), to see how it works.

```
    /* Get the current time and convert it to a double */
    gettimeofday(&tim, NULL);
    now = tim.tv_sec + (tim.tv_usec / 1000000.0);
```

We see here that it first gets the current time of day.

```
    /* Get the uptime and calculate when that was */
    uptime(&uptime_secs, &idle_secs);
    up_since_secs = (time_t) ((now - uptime_secs) + 0.5);
```

Next, it gets the actual uptime in seconds as reported by the kernel, and which would otherwise have been reported if you hadn't used `-s`. It then subtracts that number of seconds from the current time, rounding to the nearest second.

Thus, if the system clock is adjusted, the output of `-s` will have a corresponding change.